# Как убрать кнопки в элементе управления Wizard?

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, c#

Подскажите, можно ли убрать кнопки навигации внизу Wizardа, оставив SideBar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все, разобрался)

```
<asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server">
    <StartNavigationTemplate>
    </StartNavigationTemplate>
    <StepNavigationTemplate>
    </StepNavigationTemplate>
    <FinishNavigationTemplate>
    </FinishNavigationTemplate>
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" runat="server" Title="Step 1">
        </asp:WizardStep>
        <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep2" runat="server" Title="Step 2">
        </asp:WizardStep>
    </WizardSteps>
</asp:Wizard>
```